# Regarding DeepLinking in Android App

Tags: android, web, google-play, apk, deep-linking

**Problem:**

So, what I need is that I want to have different download links for my android app which will ultimately redirect to playstore.
And for my app; downloaded from each different link I want some different functionality on the basis of a parameter passed from the link.

*What can be done?*

I have heard about DeepLinking. I want to know whether it is even possible to achieve what I am thinking? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found www.branch.io. Works like a charm.